# Xcode don't running on a real device after update in Xcode 12.5

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter

After updating Xcode 12.5 whenever I try to run an app on my real device getting this warning. After the warning, it shows installing and running but never run. It works fine in simulator issues only with a real device:

```
Running Xcode build...                                                  
                                                   
 └─Compiling, linking and signing...                        56.3s
Xcode build done.                                           154.8s
Traceback (most recent call last):                                      
  File "/tmp/838A57CD-9115-4A6D-83D2-2052083CBE47/fruitstrap_be947003ab8eb9f9faf0f676f538e779f5d09e96.py", line 25, in connect_command
    process = lldb.target.ConnectRemote(listener, connect_url, None, error)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'ConnectRemote'      
Traceback (most recent call last):                                      
  File "/tmp/838A57CD-9115-4A6D-83D2-2052083CBE47/fruitstrap_be947003ab8eb9f9faf0f676f538e779f5d09e96.py", line 45, in run_command
    lldb.target.modules[0].SetPlatformFileSpec(lldb.SBFileSpec(device_app))
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'modules'            
Traceback (most recent call last):                                      
  File "/tmp/838A57CD-9115-4A6D-83D2-2052083CBE47/fruitstrap_be947003ab8eb9f9faf0f676f538e779f5d09e96.py", line 74, in safequit_command
    process = lldb.target.process                                       
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'process'            
Installing and launching...                                             
(This is taking an unexpectedly long time.)       ⣻
```

Comment: There are some potential answers: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/31179

Comment: This is the current solution: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/31179#issuecomment-830184757

Comment: thanks for your answer I'm using flutter. so can you give me some solution for flutter